# What does $V^*$ means?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

What does it mean to have an "$f \in V^*$" in terms of a transformation?
The chapter in the book it is in is about dimensions in vector spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$V^*$ is the dual space of the vector space $V$. Sometimes it is the *algebraic* dual space, which means the collection of all linear functions from $V$ to the base field $K$ (usually $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$). Other times it is the *continuous* dual space, which means the collection of all *continuous* linear functions from $V$ to the base field. (In this latter case $V$ is assumed to be a topological vector space and $K$ is assumed to be a topological field.)

With what limited context you have supplied, my guess would be that either you are talking about the algebraic dual space, or you are dealing with $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$ with their usual topology (in which case the two notions coincide).

Answer (score 1):

$f \in V^*$ means $f: V \to K$, where $K$ is the base field of the vector space $V$. Usually $K$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

**Edit:** and $f$ is linear

Comment: Not just this, but also that $f$ is linear.

Comment: Yes! Sorry, I try to explain in a simple way and forget it.